# Relationship between JSP and Java EE

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee

Is JSP part of the whole Java EE package? How are they related?

Answer (score 18):

Java EE is a very big box.  It includes:

1. Servlets and JSPs for the web tier,
2. EJBs - stateless and stateful session, entity, and message driven beans,
3. RMI for Java-to-Java remoting (also part of Java SE),
4. JDBC for relational database access (also part of Java SE),
5. JMS for messaging,
6. JTA for transaction monitoring,
7. JNDI naming and directory services,
8. Web services - SOAP, REST, RPC-XML,
9. E-mail,
10. Maybe others that I'm forgetting.

Plus containers that handle pooling, threading, lifecycle, etc.

As you can see, JSPs are just a small part of the larger whole.

You can accomplish a great deal with just a servlet/JSP engine (e.g., Tomcat or Jetty), servlets/JSPs, and JDBC.  Any web app that exposes database CRUD via the web can be written with just these technologies.

Answer (score 3):

Java EE is composed of web applications, enterprise applications and management/security components.

JSP (along with JavaServer Faces, Servlets, etc..) is a piece of Java EE's "Web Application Technology".

[Further reading directly from Sun](http://java.sun.com/javaee/technologies/)

Answer (score 2):

JSP is outdated now. I think Expert group should remove JSP from Java EE and it should continue as a separate JSR. Servlet and JSF should be used for creating web applications.

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding JSP is a part of the Java EE "family", providing a frontend or web-based access to Java applications.

Answer (score 1):

Java EE is made up of many specifications. For example, Java EE 6.0 has spec links here:
http://java.sun.com/javaee/technologies/javaee6.jsp

Some specifications can be implemented in non-Java EE containers, such as Tomcat webserver.  So, they include jsps and servlets though they implement just a tiny bit of Java EE.

So, you can look at here for more about JSP. http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/

It is just a tiny part of the overall Java EE framework, but you don't have to use a Java EE container to use JSPs.

Answer (score 1):

JSP has been part of Java EE since the start, just after servlets came into being. JSPs are converted into java servlets (source code), then compiled into byte code before being used.

It would be interesting for you to take a look at the source code generated (if your container keeps the source).

A lot of frameworks use JSP as a basis for the 'view' part. JSF can uses Facelets instead of JSPs as a base.

Answer (score 1):

Good to see you marching towards the learning path of Java technologies...:)

In a client server programming environment, there are certain technologies which help you code / program on the client(ex- html, javascript etc.) and certain technologies which you use to code for server side processing (ex- servlets, JSP etc.) Brief description of the Acronyms asked for are as-

- JSP - A server side technology used for dynamically generating web pages.
  Java Script - A client side scripting technology used for validating the forms input inserted by client.
- Java EE - A platform used for server programming in Java.
- JDBC - An API coded in Java which enables to provide access to connect to database and fetch / insert / update data.
- Java SE - A platform used to program and deploy portable applications for general use.

urls provided in Resource section may be helpful in you learning...All the best
Source(s):

http://java.sun.com ,
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform,_Standard_Edition
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform,_Enterprise_Edition