# Java EE and Servlets and JSP

Tags: jakarta-ee

Is the following statement correct?

```
Java EE includes Servlets and JSP
```

Is the above statement correct?
What are some other key features in Java EE I have to know?

Comment: Note that J2EE is updgraded and renamed to Java EE over 4 years ago. Keep yourself up to date. In fact, any book/tutorial/article which mentions literally "J2EE" is far outdated.

Comment: sounds like someone is prepping for an interview...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Relationship between JSP and JEE/J2EE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1515190/relationship-between-jsp-and-jee-j2ee)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is the above statement is correct?

Yes, Servlet and JSP are part of the **Java EE** specification.

> what some other key features in Java EE I have to know?

It all depends on your needs. But here are some other parts of Java EE (non exhaustive):

- JPA
- JMS
- EJB
- JTA
- CDI
- JAX-WS
- JAX-RS
- JCA

Comment: Note that over a half of them is not part of J2EE. But for JEE6, it's correct. [Here's another overview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2296678/where-can-i-find-a-list-of-all-the-reference-implementations-for-jee6).

Answer (score 1):

> Is the above statement is correct?

Yes, that's correct.

> what some other key features in Java EE I have to know?

EJB and JMS, among others.

Answer (score 0):

Servlet and JSP are part of the Java EE specification. Here is an overview of [Java EE Feature List](http://docs.sun.com/source/817-2177-10/djovervu.html)