# What is the diffrence between Java EE and (JSP and Servlet)?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Relationship between JSP and Java EE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1515190/relationship-between-jsp-and-jee-j2ee)

I am working with JSP and Servlets but I always come across Java EE as a fully different thing. So can someone help and explain the difference?

Comment: Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1515190/relationship-between-jsp-and-jee-j2ee. Then if you have any more questions google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java Enterprise Edition (By the way J2EE is and old way to call it. Since version 5, the Java EE acronym is used.) is the official stack of technologies designed for enterprise programming in Java. It's currently maintained by Oracle Corporation. It's released separately from Java Standard Edition. You can see the list of technologies Java EE brings about [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/tech/index-jsp-142185.html).
Both Servlets and JSP are part of Java EE stack of technologies.

Comment: Can you please tell me when to use EJB and JSF ? Do i have to learn them or i can just stick with Servlets and JSP ?

Comment: @ITLife EJB and JSF are designed to accomplish different tasks. When you consider 4-tier system (database, persistence, business, presentation), EJB (Enterprise JavaBeans) is a persistence and business tiers technology. JSF (JavaServer Faces), on the other hand, is a presentation tier technology.

Comment: Speaking of whether you should use it, it's completely up to you. It also heavily depends on what architecture your system has, what the goals are, and so on. There are lots of things to consider before making a decision.

Comment: Thank you @Ganga for your answers,Now i think i have a better understanding of it.

Answer (score 1):

Java EE is a plateform that contains different tools, mainly used to create distribued and multi-tiered application. basically it's a set of API and containers. It's long to explain what is the Java EE plateform, I've read [this documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnaaw.html) to know more about this wide technology.

Servlet is a part of JavaEE, it's a type of class used to send and receive HTTP request.
JSP are a special kind of servlet integrated in an HTML page.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response .
Can you please tell me when to use EJB and JSF ?
Do i have to learn them or i can just stick with Servlets and JSP ?
Thank you again

Comment: @ITLife EJB are special elements that are executed in a EJB container, they are usefull depending on there use, there are 3 type of Session Beans and there is also Message Beans. I suggest you read the doc i gave in the answer it's quite precise. Also good doc : https://blogs.oracle.com/enterprisetechtips/entry/a_sampling_of_ejb_3. If you are new to JEE start using Servlet and JSP then when you will have understand enough the plateform you may consider learning EJB and JSF.

Answer (score 1):

well, JSP and servlets are themselves part of Java EE. Let's understand Java EE in some casual terms.

1. If you writing your own server, deploying it on a port and running it and clients open socket connection with it and interacting with it, then its Core Java. However, if you are using some server like JBoss, Apache Tomcat, then it's Java EE. Because you deploy your application on them and run it, that's it, you don't need to worry about all underlying details.
2. If you writing your own logic on server side to process every single bit of information from clients, then It's core Java. But if you using servlets API, utilizing pre-cooked request and response objects then it's Java EE.

Answer (score 0):

**Java EE** is a Java Enterprise Edition (specifications) which contains a lot of technologies. The platform provides an API and runtime environment for developing and running enterprise software, including network and web services, and other large-scale, multi-tiered, scalable, reliable, and secure network applications.

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform,_Enterprise_Edition

**Java Servlets** is a basic mechanism to create web application. Actually, servlet is a Java class used to extend the capabilities of servers that host applications access via a request-response programming model. Although servlets can respond to any type of request, they are commonly used to extend the applications hosted by Web servers.

- http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr154/index.html
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Servlet

**JavaServer Pages (JSP)** technology provides a simplified, fast way to create dynamic web content. JSP technology enables rapid development of web-based applications that are server- and platform-independent.

- http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/jsp/index.html
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaServer_Pages

**JavaServer Pages Standard Tag Library (JSTL)** is a component of the Java EE Web application development platform. It extends the JSP specification by adding a tag library of JSP tags for common tasks, such as XML data processing, conditional execution, loops and internationalization.

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaServer_Pages_Standard_Tag_Library